# AngularJS Jasmine - How to Test Return Value of a Directive's Link Function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have a directive that looks like:

```
myApp.directive('inputCheck', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element){
            element.keydown(function(event){
                return event.which == 46
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The above checks whether a user clicked on the keyboard `delete` key.  I can set up my Jasmine unit test for it using the following:

```
describe('inputCheckTest', function(){
    it('should return true when delete key is pressed', function(){
        var scope = inputCheckElement.scope();
        var event = jQuery.Event('keydown');
        event.which = 46;
        inputCheckElement.trigger(event);
        // How do I check that the returned value from the link function is true?
    });
});
```

How do you write a truthy check on the return value in this unit test?

Comment: Who do you think would be getting the return from an event handler anyway? Since nobody will see it, does it even matter what the return is?

Answer (score 0):

In Jasmine you can to assert truths using `expect(X).toBe(y);`

In your case, you're returning a boolean to see if the `delete` button was pressed. To test this you could write something like so;

```
 var pressedDelete = inputCheckElement.trigger(event);
 expect(pressedDelete).toBe(true);
```

The code is untested but it should help you with the logic.

Comment: The problem here is that inputCheckElement is a jQuery element, so `trigger` returns just chained jQuery and no result.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned function cannot be retrieved from linking function, it is an anonymous function which was registered as an event handler there.

Getting event handlers in Angular is not a trivial or well-proven task because it deals with internal objects, especially considering the fact that it is not Angular event handler but jQuery event handler.

In theory, registered event handlers can be retrieved with

```
  var events = $.cache[inputCheckElement[0][$.expando]].events;
```

`keydown` event handler is buried in this object, so it can be spied.

More solid and convenient approach is to keep jQuery participation to bare minimum, because it is a handler that should be tested, not jQuery event mechanism.

It can be done before a directive is compiled in specs, so at the time when directive link is called, `element.keydown` is already a spy, prototypically inherited from `$.prototype`:

```
var keydownHandler;
jasmine.spyOn(angular.element.prototype, 'keydown').and.callFake(function (handler) {
  keydownHandler = handler;
});
var inputCheckElement = $compile('<input input-check>')(scope);
...
expect(inputCheckElement.keydown).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(keydownHandler({ which: 46 })).toBe(true);
```

The alternative is to save all DOM-related stuff for E2E tests (generally an acceptable solution). Writing `link` unit test specs may be painful, while they will still be duplicated in E2E.